# HTML templates inside JavaScript file... What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

What I'm trying to achieve is to store HTML templates for everything that needs to be generated on the fly inside a separate js file (instead of rendering it in the page).

The `buildHtml` function how its currently setup works fine. Where I'm stuck is what if.. I've another variable inside the template object say 'input3' and its markup is something like `<div>(exact markup from commonInput)</div>`

I tried using it as `input 3 : '<div>' + this.commonInput + '</div>'` but it turns out you cannot refer object properties from inside using `this` [(explained here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330686/javascript-access-own-object-property-inside-array-literal).

I could create 'input3' with full html but for big html chunks this approach is not very useful.

Looking for

1. solution to this specific problem
2. reasons if this approach is a bad idea
3. better alternatives

   ```
   $j(document).ready(function() {

   var namespace = window.namespace || {};
   namespace.feature = namespace.appName || {};

   namespace.feature.templates = {

   input1  :   '<div>'+
                   '<p class="abc">Hey {username}</p>'+
               '</div>',

   input2  :   '<div>'+
                   '<div class="description">{description}</div>'+
               '</div>',

   commonInput :   '<div class="common">Common code</div>'

   };

   namespace.feature.module = function() {

   var container  = $j('#container'),
       t = namespace.feature.templates;

   var buildHtml = function(type) {
       var tmpHtml = t.input1 + t.commonInput + t.input2;
       container.append(tmpHtml);
   }

   var init = function() {
       buildHtml();
   }

   return {
       init : init,
   };

   }();

   namespace.feature.module.init();

   });
   ```

Comment: have you considered using [`_.template`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just on the top of my head.

You could write the templates as functions that build strings.

```
input3 : function(param) {
    return '<div>' + param + '</div>'
}
```

then:

```
var tmpHTML = t.input1 + t.input2 + t.input3(t.commonInput);
```

Also, i like to build my own DOM objects when building HTML. and avoid the use of hardcoded strings.

**http://mg.to/2006/02/27/easy-dom-creation-for-jquery-and-prototype**

Comment: what are your thoughts on this approach for creating content on the fly... you recommend any other approach/solution. I've a question here about that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685582/javascript-best-approach-for-managing-adding-content-on-fly-and-page-load

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your exact question is, but as far as better alternatives go,
I would suggest using jQuery templates.

Here is a benchmarking page for all the different templating engines and their performance:http://jsperf.com/dom-vs-innerhtml-based-templating

You can look at the revisions to find different combinations of engines as well as run them on different browsers to see speed differences.

**Update**: The original jquery template project is no longer active. This is the new home for the old project: https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl

I would no longer recommend jquery-templates since there are much better alternatives now. The last time I checked, [dustJs by linkedIn fork](http://linkedin.github.io/dustjs/) seems to be the most promising one.

Comment: That link has rot, unfortunately. Perhaps this is the project you mean? http://plugins.jquery.com/loadTemplate/

Comment: Took out the link and replaced with the correct one. The one you have looks similar but quite not the original.